# Modeling JSON Currency Object

Tags: swiftui, ios14

I have a question concerning modeling JSON data.

I am trying to figure out how to decode JSON exchange rate data. The JSON file consists of a date, base currency ("eur" in the example below), and some currencies with rates compared to the base currency. It would be a straight forward nested JSON object without the base currency, but with the base currency thrown in the middle without a key I'm not sure where to begin.

Do I need codingKeys for the base currency and rates? How do you handle the missing base currency key?

```
extension MoneyRates: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case base = ??
        case rates = ??
    }
}
```

Here is some Xcode Playground sample code:

```
let json =
"""
{
    "date": "2021-03-12",
    "eur": {
        "aed": 4.420217,
        "afn": 93.3213,
        "all": 123.104693,
        "amd": 628.026474,
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)


class MoneyRates: Decodable {
    let date: String
    let base: String
    var rates: [String: Double] = [:]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly for this particular JSON I'd use traditional `JSONSerialization`

```
struct MoneyRates {
    let date: String
    let base: String
    let rates: [String: Double]
}

let json =
"""
{
    "date": "2021-03-12",
    "eur": {
        "aed": 4.420217,
        "afn": 93.3213,
        "all": 123.104693,
        "amd": 628.026474,
    }
}
"""

do {
    let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(json.utf8)) as! [String:Any]
    var keys = Array(result.keys)
    if let dateIndex = keys.firstIndex(of: "date"),
        let date = result[keys[dateIndex]] as? String, keys.count == 2 {
        keys.remove(at: dateIndex)
        let base = keys.first!
        let rates = MoneyRates(date: date, base: base, rates: result[base] as! [String:Double])
        print(rates)
    }
    
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks vadian for your help. Now to get it to work with my API!